# Is it possible to create a multi-lingual webpage on GitHub Pages without Jekyll?

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I have create a one-page template in English which I am planning on hosting on GitHub Pages<sup>1</sup>.

It's a very simple resume website, so I don't need anything as fancy as Jekyll. Is there a way to offer multi-language support for the website?

I was thinking of translating my `index.html` file into a couple of other languages, and then making some sort of JavaScript popup whereby if a user clicks on one of the flags it would re-load the page with the translated html file. Is this possible? Or perhaps there is a better way of achieving this?

<sub>1. God bless them for offering this service for free!</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here, but there are plenty of JS plugins such as translate.js that enable client-side translation as long as a dictionary is provided.

Comment: Not sure how to, I posted as a guest. @pnuts